# How to create image map in wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create image map as same as this site http://www.landcom.com.au/ and show the map in same window when i clicked the image. please any body help me with details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will allow you to build exact-match image maps as the reference site, but worth a try:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/imagemapper/